# Performance impact of CoreAnimation in IOS Apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

Is there any significant impact on iOS application performance in terms of memory and speed, if we use CoreAnimation instead of UIKit animation?

I am a little bit confused on which one to use.

Thanks.

Comment: UIKit animations relies on Core Animation

Comment: [I would recommend](http://ronnqvi.st/clear-animation-code/) using the highest level abstraction that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

UIKit is a framework offered by Apple to make creation of UI faster and easier. So instead of drawing every text box and handling all user interactions on it through program, you simply create an object of UITextField and let it do the rest for you.

CoreAnimation - this is used for animations like keyframe animations (think Flash), fading of objects, moving them around etc.

UIView animation are fine for the vast majority of animations. You can use core animation only if you're going to be performing more advanced animation paths, manipulating a lot of layers simultaneously, or just need to do something that UIView animations can't achieve. But in my application I use UIView animations for almost everything (including 3D transforms) and I don't have any problem with it. You wouldn't want to use UIView animations for a game, but for most non-game applications it should be fine. Besides, UIView animations use core animation on the back end.